# How does a plate stick to a tablemat?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, home-experiment, surface-tension, adhesion

So at my dinner table, I witness this weird phenomenon almost everday.

A wet plate if placed on the table mat sticks to it(works better if the plate is made up of steel).
I account surface tension and water's adhesive nature for this phenomenon.

When I sit at the table (on any of the chairs) and pull the plate towards me, the mat gets pulled along with the plate to the point of falling off the table(which is when i stop pulling and begin pushing)

However, when I push the plate away, the plate slides over the mat leaving it at the edge(the position it was at when I stopped pulling)and when it lands on the tablecloth(made of plastic) it is able to crumple the thing by pulling it with itself

I believe it is due to the fact that pushing increases friction but I apply the forces horizontally so it should not matter if I pull or push. Also why would it be able to pull the plastic tablecloth which is definitely heavier than the tablemat when the same push was applied in both cases. I could say that the tablecloth has a smoother surface increasing surface tension but I don't know.

I presume that both plastic tablecover and tablemat have smooth bottoms but for some reason the tale cover is difficult to slide over a bare table. So maybe all this is because of air pressure or something.

**Is there a good explanation for all this?**

[image: This is the plate I am reffering to]

[image: The image here represents the arrangement of the plate tablemat and tablecloth. Assume there is a plastic tablecloth on the table on which the mats are kept]

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee that, no matter how it "feels" to you,  your pull and push motions have different vector directions.  A slight difference in the vertical component (especially shifting from positive to negative) is happening.   Further, the plate 'attacks' the tablecloth at an angle as it tips off the edge of the placemat.